# Android: securityException: "destination must be on external storage"

Tags: android, mobile, securityexception

I've searched thoroughly the web to find an answer, but with no result.

I've implemented some "preferences" in my Android app, including the ability to save files in any location you want.

If I choose a path on the so-called "integrated sdcard", everything is OK. But I also have a "real" external sdcard, which is mounted (in my case) in `/storage/sdcard1` symlinked to `/extSdCard` and `/mnt/extSdCard` (While the "internal" sdcard is `/storage/sdcard0` with symlinks to `/sdcard` and `/mnt/sdcard`).

On ICS I had the external at `/emmc` plus some more links I don't remember.

The problem is that if I choose a path pointing to this `extSdCard`, the app creates the folders structure but then doesn't write the downloaded file, ending with the "SecurityException" "destination must be on external storage".

But this path IS on an external storage! More: if there are problems of writing permissions, why does it create the folders? (`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is present in the manifest).

Very likely I have done something wrong; or maybe some bug?

Eclipse log:

```
11-30 11:58:29.143: D/ShareActivity(24752): doInBackground...
11-30 11:58:33.813: D/ShareActivity(24752): The response is: 200
11-30 11:58:50.283: D/ShareActivity(24752): location: Downloads
11-30 11:58:50.443: D/ShareActivity(24752): User defined folders created
11-30 11:58:50.443: D/ShareActivity(24752): path: /storage/sdcard1/temp
11-30 11:59:07.053: D/ShareActivity(24752): downloadUri: file:/storage/sdcard1/temp/test.3gpp
11-30 11:59:07.313: D/AndroidRuntime(24752): Shutting down VM
11-30 11:59:07.318: W/dalvikvm(24752): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ce3300)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752): java.lang.SecurityException: Destination must be on external storage: file:/storage/sdcard1/temp/test.3gpp
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:864)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:904)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at dentex.youtube.downloader.ShareActivity$AsyncDownload$1$1.onClick(ShareActivity.java:269)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
11-30 11:59:07.318: E/AndroidRuntime(24752):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 11:59:09.248: I/Process(24752): Sending signal. PID: 24752 SIG: 9
```

relevant code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            private File userFolder;

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String location = settings.getString("download_locations", "Downloads");
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "location: " + location);

                boolean userLocationEnabled = settings.getBoolean("enable_user_location", false);

                if (userLocationEnabled == false) {
                    if (location.equals("DCIM") == true) {
                        path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                    }
                    if (location.equals("Movies") == true) {
                        path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
                    } 
                    if (location.equals("Downloads") == true) {
                        path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                    }
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "path: " + path);
                } else {
                        userFolder = new File(settings.getString("user_location", ""));
                        path = userFolder;
                }

                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "path: " + path.toString());

                pos = position;
                AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShareActivity.this);

                helpBuilder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
                helpBuilder.setTitle("Confirm Download for:");
                helpBuilder.setMessage(" *** msg *** ");

                helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Download here", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @TargetApi(11)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mLink = links[pos];
                        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                        Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(mLink));
                        uri = Uri.parse(path.toURI() + title + "." + mExt);
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "downloadUri: " + uri);
                        request.setDestinationUri(uri);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                        }

                        if (isExternalStorageWritable() == true) {
                            enqueue = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                        }
                    }
                });

                helpBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   //...
                });

                AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
                helpDialog.show();

            }
});
```

Comment: You should post the relevant part of code here. You cannot expect people to download your code from somewhere, just to help you.

Comment: Thanks mate! Actually this is my first question ever posted... anyway I'm going to edit the text above.

Comment: There's an unfortunate tendency in the google code to preemptively refuse to try to access files through sharing mechanisms which aren't on the external storage, without bothering to check if the access is actually permitted or not.  Gmail for example has a similar issue with the sourcing of attachments.  It may be that the implementation makes fairly strict assumptions about what is an external storage - the extended storage volumes tend to be a device-vendor hack rather than a fully implemented part of android, so might not be included in the check.  In other words, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Chris. The fact is that what I'm trying to access is a "real" external sdcard (that should be easily identified like it is: external) not the "extended storage volume/device-vendor hack" usually seen as sdcard but actually part of the internal device memory. I confirm that `userFolder.mkdirs()` creates the folder but then `DownloadManager` complains when it's time to write down the downloaded file on the same dir. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [THIS ARTICLE](https://www.xda-developers.com/android/android-3-2-code-inadvertently-preventing-write-access-to-external-storage/) by Jeremy Meiss (**jerdog**) and [THIS LINK](http://www.chainfire.eu/articles/113/Is_Google_blocking_apps_writing_to_SD_cards_/) by **Chainfire**, this behavior should be "normal", as the time being. The WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE permission should be needed, but this is granted to system apps only.

As a workaround, in my activity I handle this `SecurityException` like this (in pseudo-code):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, DownloadsService.class);

try {
    intent.putExtra("COPY", false);
    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "_ID " + enqueue + " enqueued");
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, e.getMessage());

    // handle the path on etxSdCard here:
    showSomeInfo();
    intent.putExtra("COPY", true);
    tempDownloadToSdcard(request);
}

startService(intent);
```

In `DownloadsService` I have a BroadcastReceiver where I handle the finished download;
in its `onStartCommand` I retrieve the boolean extra as:

```
doCopy = intent.getBooleanExtra("COPY", false);
```

and then inside the receiver:

```
if (doCopy) copyFileToExtSdCard();
```

Hope this clarifies and helps.

Comment: So it's impossible to use `DownloadManager` in this case, right?