# Use DownloadManager to download files to real SD card, not to emulated storage

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a galaxy S4 and my problem is that i can't use the DownloadManager to download files to SD card, on emulated storage it works just fine, as for real SD card it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Destination must be on external storage: file:///mnt/extSdCard/Android/data/net.myApp/files/exercises/exec.mp4
```

Here is my code:

```
DownloadManager dwlManager=(DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

DownloadManager.Request dwlmRequest=new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://cdn..."));
File destination = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/Android/data/net.myApp/files/exercises/exec.mp4");              

dwlmRequest.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destination));
dwlManager.enqueue(dwlmRequest); //<--- Here comes the error.
```

If i set the destination as:

```
File destination = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "exec.mp4");
```

The code works just fine, because the destination comes to the emulated storage.
Also i can create files to the SD card like:

```
File f = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/Android/data/net.myApp/files/exercises/exec.mp4");
f.createNewFile();
```

It works, but i can't use the download manager with that path.

Please help.
I need to be able to download files to that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time on this problem i found a more optimal solution then copying files to an arbitrary location after download. 
The main problem is that i was setting the path to SD card incorrect.

It was:  /mnt/extSdCard/Android/data...

But on Samsung galaxy S4 it should be:   /storage/extSdCard/Android/data...

The default download manager seems to work fine with this path as destination for downloads.
On the following link i found a pretty good code for detecting paths to SD card for different devices: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-finding-sd-card-path.html

It looks haky, but for me, it seems to be the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported. There is no guarantee that `DownloadManager` has any rights to write to arbitrary paths, even if you think they refer to an SD card. Moreover, your own code that uses `/mnt/extSdCard/` may work on your device but will not work on all devices, many of which will not even have such a directory.

Comment: This is speculation not an answer based in fact.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: If you read the question, `DownloadManager` is throwing a specific `SecurityException`. If you read the `DownloadProvider` source code, you will see that the `checkFileUriDestination()` throws this exception to "check that the file URI provided for DESTINATION_FILE_URI is valid". Hence, it is not supported. `DownloadManager` (or, more accurately, `DownloadProvider`) is an ordinary app, and no app has rights to write to arbitrary paths unless run with superuser privileges.

Comment: No, you are confusing application-level checks with permissions.  They are two **entirely different** mechanisms (actually three, as permissions have two stages of enforcement).

Comment: @ChrisStratton: "No, you are confusing application-level checks with permissions" -- no, I am not. Talented programmers validate their inputs. An input to `DownloadProvider`, in this case, is the desired destination path. `checkFileUriDestination()` is validating the input, to make sure that it is a location that `DownloadProvider` is known, *a priori*, to be able to write to, regardless of device. If you feel that `checkFileUriDestination()` should use a more expansive validation, to see if the destination is actually writeable, feel free to submit a patch.

Comment: The problem is that it (and you) are **assuming** at application-level where it can and can't write without actually checking at permission- (unix-) level.  Much like the old gmail bug which unreasonably limited useful functionality, this is likely easily circumvented.  Users add external SD cards **because they want to use them** - and what better use than for large downloads?

Comment: Thanks for the post guys. That gives me a good explanation to my problem. Seems that i will have to make some haky work in oder to have this problem done. I will download the file to emulated storage than copy it to the needed path, just like suggested in the second answer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: "The problem is that it (and you) are assuming at application-level where it can and can't write without actually checking at permission- (unix-) level." -- I am not assuming anything. I am reading Java code and explaining what it does. If you don't like the current implementation, take it up with Google.

Comment: Your explanation is not of what the java code *actually* does, but rather of what it *seems* to do.

Answer (score 2):

According to this: 
[java.lang.SecurityException: Destination must be on external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116224/java-lang-securityexception-destination-must-be-on-external-storage)

It's not possible for the DownloadManager to write into files in an arbitrary location. But you can download the file to the external storage using the "Enviroment" constants, and after the download has finished, copy the file to the desired location, and finally delete the original file using the standard file API.