# correct use of URI.fromFile for set destination of downloaded file

Tags: android, uri, storage, android-download-manager

i'm still don't understand what's wrong with my app. I'm usind DownloadManager for get from a server some mp3 files and i want to put it inside /Podcasts default android folder, but i'm not able to do it.
I've try different way but without success. if i use

```
Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS));
```

an exception it's thrown:

```
java.lang.securityexception destination must be on external storage: file///Podcasts
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

you may find [this thread useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646669/android-securityexception-destination-must-be-on-external-storage). Basically, it seems that only system apps are able to reach Media Directory. Whhy don't you just use exgternal directory?

```
String pathLocalFile = getExternalFilesDir( null ).getPath()
```

would return your app's directory on external memory and you can create relevant directories there.

Comment: because the mp3 files are podcasts and that folder seems to be good for stora podcasts! So i need to create a folder for my app and store mp3 files there?